# Unable to install react-awesome-query-builder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Ive been trying to install [react-awesome-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-query-builder) in my `Vdom-Oracle JET` project, but I'm getting following error. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

`npm i react-awesome-query-builder --save`

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: vdom-chart-sample@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.4 || ^17.0.1 || ^18.0.0" from react-awesome-query-builder@5.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-awesome-query-builder
npm ERR!     react-awesome-query-builder@"^5.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @ant-design/icons@4.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/icons
npm ERR!     @ant-design/icons@"^4.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @ant-design/icons@"^4.0.0" from react-awesome-query-builder@5.3.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-awesome-query-builder
npm ERR!       react-awesome-query-builder@"^5.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (react-dom, @emotion/react, @emotion/styled, @fortawesome/react-fontawesome)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.3" from react-awesome-query-builder@5.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-awesome-query-builder
npm ERR!     react-awesome-query-builder@"^5.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Rence Abishek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rence Abishek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-07T12_45_29_407Z-debug-0.log
```

Note: If I try using `--force`, its working fine, But I'm not sure if it will become problem in future!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder@5.4.0
```

[Reference on GitHub](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/pkgs/npm/react-awesome-query-builder)